# I couldn't properly publish duplex wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, publish

I am trying to publish my duplex wcf service on a server with no success, I am able to publish it on local IIS, but when I publish it to server its address become `net.tcp://win-rhkt30stjd7/Broadcastor/BroadcasterService.svc`. As you would agree such address is not useful at all while creating the service reference on client. I tried to publish it as WCF application project, and service library project but both is giving the same result. Probably something is missing from my `Web.config` file but I don't know what it is. Please help me out here. Below is my `Web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BroadcastorServiceApp.BroadcastorService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="BroadcastorServiceApp.IBroadcastorService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any `address` part in your `NET TCP endpoint`

1 : Add a base address as below :

```
<host>
       <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8088" />
       </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

2 : add an address parameter to your net tcp endpoint as :

```
<endpoint address = "tcpEndPoint"
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          contract="BroadcastorServiceApp.IBroadcastorService"></endpoint>
```

3 : Alse give a behavior name as :

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

And add it to the service like :

```
<service name="BroadcastorServiceApp.BroadcastorService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="BroadcastorServiceApp.IBroadcastorService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Comment: I don't understand the 2 suggestion of yours, what would be the address?

Comment: nope, I still get this address `http://win-rhkt30stjd7/Broadcastor/BroadcasterService.svc?wsdl`, when I use wsDualHttpBinding this problem doesn't occur by the way.

Comment: You can change the base address `<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8088" />` to the static server address where you have hosted the service..

Comment: I already did that. And I tried wsDualHttpBinding in a clone project of this.